# FFMPEG pipe input filenames from command line on windows

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, ffmpeg

I am concatenating a bunch of files on a windows 10 box into a single file using "ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4". This works fine when I generate list.txt in the required format.

What I am wanting is to not have to generate the file first and instead pipe the filenames in as the examples [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) show for *nix.

I have tried as follows "ffmpeg -f concat safe 0 -i <(for %i in (*.ts) do @echo file '%i') -c copy output.mp4" but I get "The system cannot find the file specified.".

Any idea's how to make this work?

Comment: something like `dir /b *.ts>tempfile.txt` followed by `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i tempfile.txt -c copy output.mp4`

Comment: And I quote "What I am wanting is to not have to generate the file first and instead pipe the filenames in as the examples here show for *nix."

Comment: Most of that link talks about automatically creating the temp file inside a script (thus not generating the file manually first).  Sorry -- I wasn't quite thorough enough to find the part about named pipes.  I do not believe cmd will be able to do that.

Comment: Windows doesn't support process substitution, so not possible.

Comment: @Reino. Thank you...guess that answers the question. Do you want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Command* substitution on Unix...

```
ffmpeg -i $(some-command-that-generates-an-url/path) [...]
```

...is possible on Windows through a for-loop:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('some-command-that-generates-an-url/path') DO ffmpeg -i %A
```

*Process* substitution on the other hand, as you describe, isn't possible on Windows. Temporary files are inevitable.